# Eclipse is replacing editor window with new Search selection

Tags: eclipse

When I search for a text string (or find references in workspace) in Eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 1 Build id: 20100917-0705) I am able to double click on search results to open an editor window and brings me to that line. Let's say I do so, and it opens `MyClass.java`. I then want to see where some code is used in my jsp. So I open (again, using search results) `some_action.jsp`.

When I do this, whatever editor window was opened first (in this case, my .java) is replaced with what I open second (the .jsp). I've never encountered this behavior before, and haven't made any changes to my workspace recently. (Well, obviously I have done something, because things don't break without a cause... but I'm not aware of any changes.) This only just started happening without any known catalyst.

Is there a setting I must toggle to remove this undesired behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Files opened by multiple searches using same editor tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243743/eclipse-files-opened-by-multiple-searches-using-same-editor-tab)

Comment: This issue is still happening today, even with following the answers.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is actually the default behavior.
To toggle between the two modes use the preference `Preferences > General > Search > Reuse editors to show matches`.

Comment: Excellent! I have never experienced this, and neither have any of my fellow developers I asked. But as expected after reading your answer, I did indeed find a checkbox. Unchecking the box gave me my desired behavior. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: I just went to my coworkers desk and sure enough his exhibits this behavior as well. And his is checked. Ironically he says he's never noticed before, and like me, now that he does, it's annoying!

Comment: Thank you for posting the question. It has annoyed me in the past, but i never bothered to search for a solution before!

Comment: Awesome,it has been annoying me for a while and now that it became significant enough, 1 search and StackOverflow and there it is. #SOIsMyGoogle

Comment: I've used Eclipse some 10 years and this never happened until I switched to Neon. So I don't think this was default in the past but a new default with Neon. IMO most annoying feature ever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very useful, I think it should come unchecked by default

Comment: I did this and it worked until I restarted Eclipse. Now even the uncheck button doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do this occasionally and don't want to change the default behavior, you can open the search result from Package Explorer:

right click on the result > Show In > Package Explorer > ENTER

or with keyboard only:

select result > shift+alt+W > DOWN > ENTER > ENTER