# Eclipse keeps replacing opened tabs

Tags: eclipse, tabs

My eclipse instance has this retarded tendency of not keeping tabs that are in use. In particular, when I open a class found in a search, my active tab gets replaced by it.

I've Googled around and tried a number of solutions including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243743/eclipse-files-opened-by-multiple-searches-using-same-editor-tab). Unfortunately, since there "tabs" also refers to the tab key/character and there are also lots of issues with the tab character, that means there are lots of irrelevant search results when I tried to research on Google.

So here I am, presenting this problem here. I wonder if you guys have encountered and overcome such an annoying feature.

Comment: Why is this not the default option? Closing is so much easier than trying to find the replaced tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Search reusing the tabs is controlled by the `Reuse editors to show matches` check box in `Preferences > General > Search`

There are also similar options in the `Run/Debug` and `Team` preferences.

Comment: Update: The checkbox has to be turned off, just to clarify.