# Force eclipse to open files in a different tab

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor

I would like that each time I open a reference to another file, Eclipse will be forced to open the file in a different editor, even if the current editor has already a tab with that file.

The motivation is that I hate when I click CTRL+Left Click (or just F3) to open a reference to a variable/function/class and such... it uses my current editor to open the file, drives me nuts because I have 6 different editors open in my workspace, and I would highly like them to be utilized.

An image for illustration, in this image Eclipse is open with 4 different editors.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like this is what you like to do:
[Eclipse: Files opened by multiple searches using same editor tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243743/eclipse-files-opened-by-multiple-searches-using-same-editor-tab)

"Disable the option

Preferences > General > Search > Reuse editors to show matches"

Although this will not open a second tab for an already opened file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have limited the number of open editors in your [preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-12.htm?cp=0_4_1_25), causing them to be recycled.

Comment: I don't think that answers my question, but that's my bad, I edited my question and hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I think this is going to need screenshots. I still don't fully understand what you're asking about, then, when it comes to editors.

Comment: Sure, look at this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xvLQ.png, where Eclipse has 4 editors open, now while you are coding in one of the editors and you reference another file, it will open that file in the same editor you are focused in, which is nonsense, why wouldn't it open a file in the other editors and not disturb your focused one?

Comment: You mean the same editor *pane* and not literally the same editor?

Comment: Yes, same editor pane, not literally the same eclipse workspace, or eclipse instance. Any ideas?