# search result in Eclipse opens in tab in same panel

Tags: eclipse

When I search for something in Eclipse and the results show in the Search tab, whenever I click on a result (for example, a .java) it opens in a new tab next to the Search tab (in the lower panel), instead of in a new tab next to the rest of files that are open in Eclipse (in the upper panel).

This is very annoying because I use the lower panel for "tool views" such as Console, Search, Problems, Tasks, etc and I don't want files to be opened in that panel.

I'm sure I'm missing some setting in the preferences but I can't find it and this behaviour is driving me crazy.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to finally find a solution which helped me, so this should work for you as well.

Try the following:

- drag the Search view out of its current position and anchor it in a different place (I dragged it just above the Explorer view on the left)
- double click on a search result - it should open in the panel with all other files
- next drag the Search view again to anchor it as the bottom panel, and try to open a search result again

You may need to play around with this a few times before it works, but it took me less than a minute to fix.

It seems that the way how you anchor the Search view has influence where the files will open after you double click.

[See the original post which helped me find the solution](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=1281981)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my variant of Eclipse (MCUXpresso) by altering: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Search -> Reuse editors to show matches.